# popmenu item is not responding on click

Tags: java, swing

I have written this code to add and delete a row in my table using popup menu, but this code neither delete nor add a row to the table when I click respective options (ADD and DELETE) on popup menu, please help.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


    public class B extends MouseAdapter {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Object rows[][] = new Object[5][3];
        String colums[] = {"A","B","C"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows,colums);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("ADD");
        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("DELETE");
        Object[] row = {"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"};

        public static void main(String arg[]) {
            new B();
        }

        B() {
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            table.addMouseListener(this);
            item1.addMouseListener(this);
            item2.addMouseListener(this);
            popup.add(item1);
            popup.add(item2);
            table.add(popup);
            frame.add(scroll);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent click) {

            if(click.getSource()==table && click.getButton()==3)    
                popup.show(table,click.getX(),click.getY());
            else if(click.getSource()==item1)
                model.addRow(row);
            else if(click.getSource()==item2)
                model.removeRow( table.rowAtPoint(click.getPoint()) );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please do not ask same question twice : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523584/jpopupmenu-is-not-displayed-on-right-click

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing objects using `==` (to compare references of two components) you should use equals method . So change the following from:

```
click.getSource()==table
```

To

```
click.getSource().equals(table)
```